# Reading XML and undeclared namespace

Tags: c#, xml

I got this error message when I try to read the XMLfile

```
 Unhandled Exception: System.Xml.XmlException: 'xi' is an undeclared namespace. Line 12, position 18.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg, Int32 lineNo, Int32 linePos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.LookupNamespace(NodeData node)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ElementNamespaceLookup()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
```

Code to read XML:

```
   XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("file.xml");
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // Do some work here on the data.
        Console.WriteLine(reader.Name);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

The xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>    
<doh> 
        <!-- Available Resources-->
        <servers>
                <xi:include href="file.xml"/>
        </servers>
```

Comment: Your XML is invalid, there is no `xi` namespace defined.

Comment: xi is an alias to a namespace, but the xmlns:{alias}={namespace-uri} is not defined. So, you are using an 'undeclared prefix'

Comment: I have no choice. I must use the xml file as is. is there a trick? or workaround to ignore xi?

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Comment: You're right - you have no choice. You will never make this work. The XML is simply not valid. It's not a matter of your lack of knowledge - the XML is simply garbage. The only way you will meet the requirement to read this file is if the people who created the file change it. Otherwise, time to find a new job.

Comment: @JohnRyann, if someone requires to process such XML, internally pre-process it before reading to simply add missing namespace.

Comment: See this suggestion, turning off namespaces using an XMLTextReader http://stackoverflow.com/a/4039678/655625

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are wanting to use XInclude.  You must define which namespace the *xi* prefix maps to.  The easiest why is too include the namespace mapping in the root element.

```
  <doh xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
```

Note that the *XmlTextReader* will not include the "file.xml".  You will have to 'include' by some other code.  A good background paper on the XInclude can be found on MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302291.aspx

Comment: I can not change the xml file. it is a requirement to use it as is. is there a way to ignore it? consider it as a comment?

Comment: The XML that you show is wrong it is not valid XML.  All xml readers in any language will report an error.  You should go back to the producer of the XML and get them to produce correct XML.